# Firefox 31 keeps asking for Proxy Authentication

Tags: networking, firefox, proxy, authentication

I read a lot of questions through the internet about this, but I didn't find any one that worked for me. In Options>Advanced>Connection I have chosen the Manual Proxy Configuration, I have entered my network proxy hostname and port. I also checked the check box `Use this proxy server for all protocols`. I also checked the 'Do not prompt for authentication if password is saved'.

Then I entered `about:config` and I toggled the `signon.autologin.proxy` to true.

None of the above settings helped me. Firefox keeps asking for user/pass for proxy authentication in every click I made. Sometimes it keeps asking more than 10 times for opening a webpage.

Any idea please?

Comment: Are you behind an NTLM proxy, if so then I guess this is a very old problem.

Comment: As far as I know no, it is SQUID server. Is there anyway to chek?

Comment: What are the solutions for NTLM and not NTLM proxy ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have your proxy configured correctly.
I use the `manual` setting.

Also check the `"Do not prompt for authentication if password is saved"`.

Then initiate a page load, for example www.google.com, just so that Firefox asks for your proxy user and password.

When Firefox asks you to save the password, please do so.

Then, please install the following addon:
[AutoAuth](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autoauth/)

You should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

> When using Firefox through an ISA server, Firefox repeatedly prompts for proxy authentication, even though the correct credentials have been entered and applied.
>
> Resolution:
>
> In the address bar, type about:config. A warning appears.
>
> Click to proceed. A variety of configuration options appears.
>
> In the Filter box, type network.negotiate.
>
> Double-click network.negotiate-auth.allow-proxies to toggle between
> true and false. The option must be set to false. (It seems
> counterintuitive, but you set it to false to make it work with the ISA
> proxy.)

Old ffox screenshots and details here: https://kb.globalscape.com/KnowledgebaseArticle10522.aspx